# How to get id of a spinner in main activity from a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have a **recyclerview**, I have designed a row which is inflated in the **adapter**,I want to get hold of the id of the spinner to perform some action with it which I am unable to do.
This is my **ApolloActivity.java** where I am trying to inflate a recylcer view, in **onClick()** of the fab i want the id of the spinner.

```
private List<ApolloPharmacyEntity> entity = null;
        private RecyclerView rv;
        private FloatingActionButton fab;
        Spinner spinner;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Apollo Pharmacy");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_apollo);
            rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
            Log.i("TAG","recycler view"+rv);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     Context context=view.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = null;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.apollopharmacy_listrow,null);
                spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);//this is becoming null

                    String Text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.i("TAG","spinnervalue"+spinner);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Apollo.this, Cart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();

`

> This is my adapter

```
public static class EntityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tabName;
        TextView gobacktomenutv;
        Spinner spinner;
        String[] itemCount = { "1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8","10"};
        RelativeLayout addrl;
        Dialog dialog;

        EntityViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            tabName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);


            ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(itemView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemCount);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(aa);



        }
    }
    List<ApolloPharmacyEntity> details;

    ApolloPharmacyAdapter(List<ApolloPharmacyEntity> details){
        this.details = details;
    }
    @Override
    public ApolloPharmacyAdapter.EntityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.apollopharmacy_listrow, viewGroup, false);
        ApolloPharmacyAdapter.EntityViewHolder pvh = new ApolloPharmacyAdapter.EntityViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ApolloPharmacyAdapter.EntityViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tabName.setText(details.get(position).getTabName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return details.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

> apollopharmacy_listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout3"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout2">
    <TextView
        android:text="ASPIRIN-250 mg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#224e6d"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout3"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="6 tab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#224e6d"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="1 STRIP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#224e6d"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_rounded"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Transfer"
                android:text="ADD"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativelayout3"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="₹"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="#82BCB4"
            android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" />
        <TextView
            android:text="26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="#224e6d"
            android:textStyle="bold|normal"
            android:layout_marginStart="230dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView9" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_outline"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24px"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put one method in your EntityViewAdapter class. And access it through your adapter instance in Activity .

Comment: what you want to do with the id

Comment: i want to get the spinner value of the specific spinner and auto set it in the next activity @SaurabhPadwekar

Answer (score 0):

In your **ApolloActivity.java**'s `onCreate()` method you have not set your `ApolloPharmacyAdapter` to your RecyclerView. Hence the layout of `apollopharmacy_listrow.xml` is not inflated.

Please use `rv.setAdapter()` method in `onCreate()`

Also if there is no detail found for listrow RecyclerView will not inflate the listrow. Spinner cannot be used like this in onCreate() as there maybe more than one instances of Spinner depending on number of rows in RecyclerView.

You will have to specify which spinner do you want to refer to from you Activity.

I can help if you elaborate on what exactly do you want to achieve by sending a spinner item to next Activity.

Comment: i have used rv.setAdapter() inside my initializeAdapter() already, I missed that part to post it here,i have updated my code. Even after using rv.setAdapter() its giving null. I want caluclate the total cost of items by using the spinner value @Vaibhav Jain

Comment: As you said I am not able to get the specif spinner in the recycler view, to auto set the spinner in the next Activity depending upon the previous Activity.Could you please help me with this @Vaibhav Jain